# Return.portfolio function using different weights row as input

Tags: r

I would like to compute the returns of different portfolios by using Return.portfolio function that requires as input the return series and the associated weights of the stocks.
I want the function to compute the return using the first row of variable "weights" and store the results, than consider the next weights row and keep on the computation.

I was using this code but is not working

```
first.date <- '2000-01-01'
last.date <- '2020-01-01'
freq.data <- "monthly"
tickers <- c("ENI.MI","ENEL.MI","IBE.MC","BBVA.MC","TEF.MC","DTE.DE","BNP.PA","FTSEMIB.MI")


l.out  <-  yf_get( tickers = tickers,
                   first_date = first.date,
                   last_date = last.date,
                   freq_data = freq.data)
l.out$price_adjusted
l.wide  <- yf_convert_to_wide(l.out)
l.prices <- l.wide$price_adjusted
l.prices=as.data.frame(l.prices)
l.prices <- xts(l.prices[ , -1], order.by = as.Date(l.prices[,1], "%Y-%m-%d"))
l.ret <- l.wide$ret_adjusted_prices
l.ret=as.data.frame(l.ret)
l.ret <- xts(l.ret[ , -1], order.by = as.Date(l.ret[,1], "%Y-%m-%d"))
l.ret = l.ret[-1,]

for (i in 1:nrow(l.prices)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(l.prices)) {
    if (is.na(l.prices[i,j])){
      l.prices[i,j]= l.prices[i-1,j]}}}
summary(l.prices)


for (i in 1:nrow(l.ret)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(l.ret)) {
    if (is.na(l.ret[i,j])){
      l.ret[i,j]= 0}}}
summary(l.ret)

l.ret <- l.ret[,c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,6)]
l.prices <- l.prices[,c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,6)]





SP = seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.05)
results = data.frame(lapply(SP,
                            \(y) epo(
                              x = x,
                              signal = s,
                              lambda = 10,
                              method = "simple",
                              w = y
                            )))
rownames(results)= c("ENI.MI","ENEL.MI","IBE.MC","BBVA.MC","TEF.MC","DTE.DE","BNP.PA")
colnames(results) <-c(SP)

# Computing the weights
results_transposed= data.frame(t(results))
colnames(results_transposed) <- c("ENI.MI","ENEL.MI","IBE.MC","BBVA.MC","TEF.MC","DTE.DE","BNP.PA")
rownames(results_transposed)= c(SP)

# Each row here is a set of weight for each stock
results_transposed


# Here i want to compute the return by using every time a different row of "results_transposed"
l.ret2= l.ret[,1:7]                     # Returns series
weight2 = results_transposed            # each row is a set of weights
results2 = data.frame(lapply(weight2,
                             \(y) Return.portfolio(R = l.ret2, 
                                                   weights = y)))
```